# Native in 'Ionic View' but not native in the .apk Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have this function that as if ios, android (native) or otherwise the alert is different:

```
 if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
     navigator.notification.alert(
         $filter('translate')(message),
         function() {},
         $filter('translate')(title),
         "OK"
     );
 } else {
     $ionicPopup.alert({
         title: $filter('translate')(title),
         template: $filter('translate')(message),
         okType: 'button-assertive'
     });
 }
```

This function is made to come out alerts in the browser, in Android and iOs, on the Ionic View go OK, but when you install the .apk on Android not working.

What can happen?

Regards and thanks.

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I don't have installed the plugin `cordova-plugin-dialogs`, so I solved with the command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

Thanks a lot!